# Retrieve image coordinates (X, Y) from geographic coordinates in NetCDF file using Numpy

Tags: python, netcdf, numpy, sentinel-3

I'm trying to retrieve image coordinates (X, Y) from geographic coordinates in NetCDF file (Sentinel 3 data) using Numpy. The problem is that the final pixel is too close to the desired pixel but not the closest to it (about one or two pixel far away from the closest in x, y or both x,y). I'm using Numpy's `norm()`,  `min()` and `where()` function. The code is presented below:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

# Read the NetCDF file with the geographic coordinates information
nc_coord = Dataset('coords.nc', 'r')

lat = nc_coord.variables['latitude'][:]
# Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data
lat = lat.data
lon = nc_coord.variables['longitude'][:]
lon = lon.data

# define your point:
target_lon, target_lat = 23.779675, 35.33786
# lat and lon are x,y matrices, we will add another dimension z in order to stack them
lat = lat[:, :, np.newaxis]
lon = lon[:, :, np.newaxis]
grid = np.concatenate([lat, lon], axis=2)
vector = np.array([target_lat, target_lon]).reshape(1, 1, -1)
subtraction = vector - grid

# vector subtraction
dist = np.linalg.norm(subtraction, axis=2)

# query where in the 2D matrix is the closest point to your points of interest (?)
result =  np.where(dist == dist.min())

# this is your lat/lon geo point translated to a x, y position in the image matrix
target_x_y = result[0][0], result[1][0]
```

Can you figure out what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you are using a swath dataset (i.e. not using a regular grid). If you were using a regular grid, you'd just calculate the pixel number from the e.g. corner coordinates. I think

```py
geolocation = Dataset(fname)
points = np.array([geolocation.variables['lon'][:],
                   geolocation.variables['lat'][:]
                  ])
# Exact point
point = np.array([3.60829699, 44.41841389])
dist = np.linalg.norm(point[:, None, None] - points, axis=0)
i, j = np.where(dist == dist.min())
# Should evaluate to True
print(np.allclose(point, points[:, i, j].squeeze()))
print(dist.min())
# Not Exact point, actually closest to neighbouring pixel
point = np.array([3.605, 44.421])
dist = np.linalg.norm(point[:, None, None] - points, axis=0)
i, j = np.where(dist == dist.min())
# Should evaluate to False, as test point not in arrays
print(np.allclose(point, points[:, i, j].squeeze()))
print(dist.min())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately your code gives me exactly the same results as the code above. It finds a pixel value like (1982, 4663) while the closest pixel is (1981, 4663).

Comment: Are you sure this discrepancy isn't due to 0 and 1 based indices? I tested this with my data and it works as expected. Can you make your data available?